# Flask unittest and sqlalchemy using all connections

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've just run into an issue running unittests on my flask app after I had roughly 100 unittests. All unittests will pass, but when run all at once they will fail with the following error:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Everything is running in a virtualbox/vagrant/ubuntu12.04 instance on local machine. My postgres max_connections is set to 100 so I'm assuming that the connections aren't closing and after running 100 tests I use up all the available ones.

This person [Flask unit tests with SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL exhausts db connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117094/flask-unit-tests-with-sqlalchemy-and-postgresql-exhausts-db-connections) looks like they are having the same exact problem. Mike/Zzzeek (sqlalchemy dev) even responded to it saying that something may be happening in create_app() so I've included that as well below.

Does this mean I'm not closing my connections somewhere? All of these errors are triggered by `db.create_all()` in my setUp() method of my unittest.

# test.py

```
class TestCase(DataMixin, Base):
    """Base test class"""

    def create_app(self):
        return create_app(TestConfig())

    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
```

# app.py

```
def create_app(config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Config
    app.config.from_object(BaseConfig())
    if config is not None:
        app.config.from_object(config)

    # Extensions
    db.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)

    # Blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(core_blueprint, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(accounts_blueprint, url_prefix='/account')
    app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint, url_prefix='/admin')
    app.register_blueprint(cart_blueprint, url_prefix='/cart')

    # Login Manager
    login_manager.setup_app(app, add_context_processor=True)
    login_manager.login_view = "accounts.login"
    login_manager.user_callback = load_user

    # Templates
    app.jinja_env.globals['is_admin'] = is_admin
    app.jinja_env.globals['is_staff'] = is_staff

    @app.context_processor
    def inject_cart():
        cart = count = None
        if current_user.is_authenticated():
            cart = current_user.get_cart()
        return dict(cart=cart)

    # Error Handling
    @app.errorhandler(404)
    def page_not_found(error):
        return render_template('404.html'), 404

    return app
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask unit tests with SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL exhausts db connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117094/flask-unit-tests-with-sqlalchemy-and-postgresql-exhausts-db-connections)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17998485/1870623 and a great explination here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16390645/1870623

The solution is to add `db.get_engine(self.app).dispose()` to the tearDown()

```
class TestCase(Base):
    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        db.get_engine(self.app).dispose() # This
```

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE**: Tested and fixed

Instead of making a new connection and re-creating your database every time (slow), you can use subsessions and do a rollback after each test.

The connection are reused, so this also fix the problem you're having.

```
class TestCase(Base):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.app = create_app(MyConfig())
        cls.client = cls.app.test_client()
        cls._ctx = cls.app.test_request_context()
        cls._ctx.push()
        db.create_all()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        db.get_engine(cls.app).dispose()

    def setUp(self):
        self._ctx = self.app.test_request_context()
        self._ctx.push()
        db.session.begin(subtransactions=True)

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.rollback()
        db.session.close()
        self._ctx.pop()
```

If you need to also make an instance of the application for each test, just add it to the `setUp` method but leave it also in `setUpClass`.

Full test example below requires flask_sqlalchemy and psycopg2. Create a test database named "test" and set its connection limit to 15.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from unittest import TestCase as Base


db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app


class MyConfig(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://localhost/test"
    TESTING = True


class TestCase(Base):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.app = create_app(MyConfig())
        cls.client = cls.app.test_client()
        cls._ctx = cls.app.test_request_context()
        cls._ctx.push()
        db.create_all()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()   

    def setUp(self):
        self._ctx = self.app.test_request_context()
        self._ctx.push()
        db.session.begin(subtransactions=True)

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.rollback()
        db.session.close()
        self._ctx.pop()


class TestModel(TestCase):

    def test_01(self):
        pass

    def test_02(self):
        pass

    def test_03(self):
        pass

    def test_04(self):
        pass

    def test_05(self):
        pass

    def test_06(self):
        pass

    def test_07(self):
        pass

    def test_08(self):
        pass

    def test_09(self):
        pass

    def test_10(self):
        pass

    def test_11(self):
        pass

    def test_12(self):
        pass

    def test_13(self):
        pass

    def test_14(self):
        pass

    def test_15(self):
        pass

    def test_16(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import unittest
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: setUpClass is run before create_app() is called so there is no db initialized yet. Although this is interesting for unittest performance. Even if it did work I think I would still have some sort of issue in my code not closing connections. This would just be a workaround to a problem that might get exposed in production.

Comment: Fixed and added a full example.

Comment: Juan-Pablo, Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I don't care about points at all but I answered my own question, so the next person wouldn't be as frustrated. I believe your solution is maybe an overall better solution to the problem as it solves it and clearly makes the tests run waaaay faster, but I was unable to get it to work either. I could run what you have but, I was violating unique constraints on my database since the database wasn't really rolling back, between tests. I will continue to research. Thank you for your time

Comment: This has the issue that you cant run tests in parallel anymore, since it is required to run them  sequentially since the transactions cant overlap.